# Connecting remote SQL Server to PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Can any one explain the connection string from the parameters below:

```
server IP : 192.168.137.4
Windows Authentication : Windows Authentication
UserName : DELL-M102Z\dell
Database : DataProd 
Network Protocol : <default>
Product Name : Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition
Server Name : DELL-M102Z\SQLEXPRESS
Instance Name : SQLEXPRESS
Computer Name : DELL-M102Z
```

I tried:

```
$serverName = "DELL-M102Z\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName
$username = "DELL-M102Z\dell"; //serverName\instanceName
$conn = mssql_connect( $serverName,$username,'');
```

...but the result I got was:

> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: DELL-M102Z\SQLEXPRESS in C:...\index.php on line 17
>       Connection could not be established.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: Use either `DELL-M102Z` or `192.168.137.4` as servername. And as user just `dell` (if that *is* the user with privileges to access the server).

Comment: by sql management studio on the sql server, i only can connect by using server name as localhost but failed when use 192.168.137.4, so what should i do to connect from remote client?

Comment: @kreamik: Consult the documentation of your database server software how to allow remote connections to it. As the error says, you have a connection issue, this can be a firewall or the server configuration and many other things. Contact the system administrator when in doubt. If you administer it your own, check the support resources of the database and server software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trying to follow this step:
http://michaelellerbeck.com/2010/03/31/cant-connect-remotely-to-sql-server-2008/
i know that i miss to activate sql browser service, and that's why i cannot connect by remote IP,

I got conclusion from that site and i must make sure that:

```
1. make sure you have allow network connection from sql server configuration tool
2. allow connection for this port in firewall
3. activate sql browser service
4. make sure port is listen as the the service provide
```

i got problem for no.3 and i'm stuck on it, this site solve the problem:
http://www.wikihow.com/Enable-Remote-Connections-SQL-2008-Express

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$myServer = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy';
$myUser = 'sa';
$myPass = 'xxxxx';

$con = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) or die("Could not connect to database: ".mssql_get_last_message()); 
if($con){
echo "connected";
}
// Select a database:
mssql_select_db('new') 
    or die('Could not select a database.');

// Example query: (TOP 10 equal LIMIT 0,10 in MySQL)
$SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Table";

// Execute query:
$result = mssql_query($SQL) 
    or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

// Get result count:
$count = mssql_num_rows($result);
print "Showing $count rows:<hr/>\n\n";

// Fetch rows:
while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    print $Row['BillNo'] . "\n";

}

mssql_close($con);
```

---

$myServer  =  'IP_Address:PORT';

Here semicolon is need to ip and port
and 
Mssql is enbaled at your cpanel