# Azure - PHP Connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, azure

I want to connect with SQL Server using PHP on Azure.

My code works successfully on my host, but the following issues occur after I deploy to Azure application service:

```
SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]
```

Code:

```
try {
      $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=1xx.xx.xx.xx;Database=MyDB", "username", "password");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();  
    }
```

`1xx.xx.xx.xx` is another remote server, I want to connect to this server from Azure.

And phpinfo.php:

```
PDO drivers : mysql, sqlsrv, pgsql
```

So I should be able to use the PDO sqlsrv function.

What do I need to set up on the Azure application service?

Comment: For clarity, is the SQL database also in Azure?

Comment: @slayer3600, No, the database is not in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Before you deploy your PHP code to Azure APP Service, I think you need to test if you PHP code can connect to the remote SQL Server on local computer successfully.

If you want to connect to remote SQL server, you must make sure that:

```
1. make sure you have allow network connection from sql server configuration tool
2. allow connection for this port in firewall
3. activate sql browser service
4. make sure port is listen as the the service provide
```

Reference:

1. [Connecting remote SQL Server to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547775/connecting-remote-sql-server-to-php).
2. [How to connect to a remote SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-sql-server/).

If it can runs correctly with no error on local computer, then deploy you app to Azure application service.

Here are two examples about connect to the MSSQL:

1.connect to a specified MS SQL Server database:

```
$c = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");
```

2.connect to a MS SQL Server database on a specified port:

```
$c = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost,1521;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");
```

Hope this helps.